# Rendering angular directive inside reactjs component

Tags: angularjs-directive, lifecycle, reactjs

I want to render an AngularJS directive inside a React component. For example, take the following directive for a carousel:

```
var reactComp = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
    return ("<div>\
      <ul rn-carousel class=\"someClass\">\
        <li className=\"someSortOfClass\">\
        </li>\
      </ul>\
     </div>");
   }
});
```

Apparently the directive is not called whatsoever. I also tried to use the `componentDidMount` function on react to insert the correct directive, but I guess it's a different environment, so that directive isn't called either.

Could anyone shed some light on this?